# Are Questions about TFS usage/commands on-topic?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

As the title says, are questions asking about TFS usage/commands on-topic? It's not really a programming question, but it *is* a programming tool. I see other questions about TFS, but they are mostly older so I can't gauge if they are no longer appropriate.

If it matters (and without actually asking my question *here*), I have an *unusual* scenario and am searching for the correct series of TFS commands to solve the issue. I'm not looking for basic stuff that can be easily found by searching the docs, Google or Stack Overflow (I've tried).

Comment: We're meta.  We won't bite (too hard).  Edit your question into this one so we can tell you if it's at least going to fly or what needs to be improved to make it something that's answerable.

Comment: By TFS, I assume you're referring to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Team_Foundation_Server, right?

Comment: As one of 6 people on Stack Overflow with a gold badge in the TFS tag, I unilaterally declare it to be fine.

Comment: I ended up asking: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53782644/491907

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The general consensus, as far as I get it, is that tools that are used primarily for programming (like TFS, or git), are on-topic on Stack Overflow.

If you're really unsure, you could share your question here (perhaps without the technical details such as error messages, etc) and ask if that specific question would be on-topic on Stack Overflow, without going in to a general discussion about TFS.

Answer (score 3):

It's fine. Like Mureinik said, it's a tool used by programmers, so questions about TFS are explicitly on-topic.

Asking a question about TFS (or `tf` CLI usage) is no different than asking about how to achieve something with Git from the CLI. People ask questions with the [tfs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfs) tag every day that relate to general TFS usage, as well as sister tags like [azure-devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/azure-devops), [tfsbuild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tfsbuild), and dozens of others.